# undetected chromedriver start error in Python

Tags: python, selenium, undetected-chromedriver

It seems for some websites I need to use undetected chromedriver for Selenium automation. I already got Selenium and chromedriver installed in a venv environment, and also ran the below to install undetected chromedriver in the venv:  `python -m pip install undetected-chromedriver`. I used the below  code to start undetected chromedriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
browser = uc.Chrome()
browser.get('any url here')
```

When I run the script in the venv I got error message. Could anyone help what was wrong?

```
PS C:\Users\user\my_venv> & c:/Users/user/my_venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
(my_venv) PS C:\Users\user\my_venv> & c:/Users/user/my_venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/user/my_venv/toughsite_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 269, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\user\my_venv\toughsite_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    browser = uc.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\user\my_venv\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self.browser_pid = start_detached(
  File "C:\Users\user\my_venv\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\dprocess.py", line 35, in start_detached
    ).start()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Comment: The answwer in the below question solved the problem:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71017921/why-is-undetected-chromedriver-not-working#new-answer

Comment: But if I used Aaron's method to successfully launch a browser, it was then shut off after some seconds. Weird.

Answer (score 4):

The simple fix is that you just have to write:

```
uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
```

And thank me later ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # call your functions here...
```

if name == main is used to ensure that the code inside that block is only executed when the script is run directly, but not when it is imported as a module into another script.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do not have your main method wrapped in

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo()
```